# Django ForeignKey: is it possible to ask for a name instead of an id?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-models, django-views

My question is about django models and foreign keys. I searched for a similar question but it seems I didn't find it.

My models are as follows:

```
class Matches(models.Model):
    day = models.ForeignKey('Day')
    team_home = models.ForeignKey('Team', related_name="home_set")
    team_away = models.ForeignKey('Team', related_name="away_set")
    golH = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    golA = models.IntegerField(null=True)

class Team(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey('League')
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Now, is there a way to get the name of the team instead of the id when I call:

```
Matches.objects.filter(day=1).values()
```

As alternative:
Is there a way to add two attributes in the Matches class, something like:
class Matches(models.Model):
...

```
def team_home_name(self)
    return self.team_home.name

def team_home_away(self)
    return self.team_away.name
```

and get them in the dictionary when I call:

```
Matches.objects.filter(day=1).values()
```

Notes:
I would like to keep the team id as foreign key.
I need to have the team name in the dictionary because what I want to pass to the template is the team name and not the team id.
I know that I can build a new dictionary with the wanted information in the view that passes the dictionary to the template, but if there is a way to do this with some django tricks at the model level it would be better.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use values('team_home__name'), it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal with all this is only to be able to access the team names from your template, then you don't have to write any additional code in your model or view to achieve that.

When you query `Matches.objects.filter(day=1)` in your view and include it in the context of your template as `matches`, you should be able to access the team names in your template like this:

```
{% for match in matches %}
   Home team is {{match.team_home.name}} and away team is {{match.team_away.name}} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is basically what I want, but I don't know why, this `{{matches}}

{% for match in matches %}
 team home is: {{ match.team_home.name}}
{%endfor%}` doesn't produce any result on the html page. Matches results to be a query set.

Comment: Possibly because your queryset is empty ?

Comment: It's not, if I'm not terribly wrong, since I'm printing it when I call the view just before passing to the template, and I see what I'm supposed to see, the 4 matches of that specific day.

Comment: Did you leave off the `.values()` in your view?

Comment: So `Matches.objects.filter(day=1)` instead of `Matches.objects.filter(day=1).values()`?

Comment: (I don't know how to make the returns work in the comments) `this_day=Day.objects.get(status='c') #current day`

`def home_page(request):
 matches=this_day.matches_set.all()
 render(request,'home.html',matches)`

Comment: What happens if you include {{ matches.count }} in your template?

Comment: Ablsolutely nothing. The page loads, though (even before was loading), but I don't see anything. This is type(matches), just to be sure we're at the same point: <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>

Comment: Can it be I'm not passing it correctly? `return render(request,'home.html',matches)` Solved, this was the problem: if I do `return render(request,'home.html',{'matches':matches})` it works.

Answer (score 5):

As bruno mentioned, you can pass objects directly to the template. However, using `values()` also you have the choice to decide what comes as the dictionary values. For example:

```
Matches.objects.filter(day=1).values('team_home__name','team_away__name')
```

Answer (score 1):

> "I need to have the team name in the dictionary because what I want to
>   pass to the template is the team name and not the team id"

**Why do you want to pass dicts to your templates ?** Django templates work with just any Python objects, including models and querysets - in fact that's the most common pattern.

Comment: What if I want to pass a list of objects?